# Problems installing Ruby with RVM

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm

I just migrated from Windows to Ubuntu, and I am trying to install Ruby 1.9.2 on Ubuntu.

I first installed RVM, and it worked fine.

I ran `RVM install 1.9.2` and everything seemed to work fine: it downloaded, configured, compiled and installed everything. At the end, I had the #complete message ... so I thought everything ran fine...

But when I type `ruby -v` , I get a message

`You can get Ruby in the following packages:
* Ruby 1.9.1
* Ruby 1.8`

I then tried `sudo apt-get ruby1.9.2`, and I had a message saying that 1.9.2 would be replaced by 1.9.1

I did `RVM install 1.8.7`, everything seems to work fine, but I have at the end the same problem: Ruby is not recognized...

Typing `which ruby` does nothing (no answer, no error message).

I am a bit desesperate here, any idea to help me ?

Many thanks in advance !

Olivier

Comment: are you forgetting to `rvm use 1.9.2` ?

Comment: typing this gives me: `Using /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180` ... but again, running ruby -v afterwards and still the same answer, asking me to install it from one of the packages...

Comment: Did you run the install script using sudo ('multi-user installation')?

Comment: PATH:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/share    otherwise, no I ran the installation of RVM using the GUI of Ubuntu ("logithèque" in French) and Ruby using `RVM install 1.9.2`

Comment: @Olivier Martin - I'd suggest removing ruby-rvm and reinstalling using the 'single-user installation' method described here: http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

Comment: OK, I will do that Luke. Thanks .. by the way, if I type `rvm list`, I received as answer: rvm rubies, then the two version I installed (1.8.7 and 1.9.2), with an arrow that points to 1.9.2 (that I set as default) ... so, strange to have "ruby -v' not working..

Comment: http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac look at step 7 on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using "apt-get broken" RVM, follow this answer for instructions how to fix: [Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395)

And here is good tutorial for RVM: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm

Answer (score 0):

[Used rails on VM running Ubuntu 11.10 but after shutdown says "rails is not installed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541925/used-rails-on-vm-running-ubuntu-11-10-but-after-shutdown-says-rails-is-not-inst/8542534#8542534)

Follow the example I provided at the bottom, it works great.

First:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove rvm
```

then...

Copy and paste this into a shell.

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

have fun.

I have had terrible luck with the packaged version of rvm, just install from source via above.